# how to update managed metadata fields using rest?

Tags: metadata, update, nodejs

I am using rest to post resources in Sharepoint and I can insert my files without problems. However, when I tried to update the metadata fields even using the unique identifier of the term I want to introduce does not work.

I am using nodejs from the server side, so the client side possible libraries are not applicable.

Below I send part of the code I use to update my data.

```
    var urlT = url + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Project%20Icon%20Library')/items(1)";

    httpntlm.post({
    url: urlT,
    username: config.sharepoint.username,
    password: config.sharepoint.password,
    headers:
      {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
        "IF-MATCH": "*",
        "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
      },
    requestDigest:XrequestDigest,
    data:data,
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the correct format?

A metadata field value is organized like this: "cachelistid";#"displayname"|"guid"

If this caching list id (forgot the exact name of this) is not available or if you simply don't want to bother caching, just use -1. Values are saved in a hidden list on the SharePoint site.

In other words, you have to insert a value similar to this:
-1;#Coffee|e092dsd8-79lb-291g-b723-83c41cb4e19f

Comment: Yes, I tried also with the format you suggested I did not work and also the server does not complain of any error.